# How to make pagination in view by using the array variable from controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm new to Laravel and I can't understand the pagination concept for an array passed from the controller to the view.

My view code

```
@foreach($aHotelRooms as $aHotelRoom)
<?php 
    //display contents
?>
@endforeach
```

Here, I would like to set pagination using `$aHotelRooms`.

I dont know how to use `$users = DB::table('table_name')->paginate(3);` and `echo $users->render();` for my `$aHotelRooms`..

Please someone help me..

Comment: Have you tried `{{$users->links()}}` ?

Comment: Yep..But I seems to be an error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with this solution.And it works for me great.

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
use DB;

    public function postHotelresults(Request $request,$page = 1)
    {
    .
    .
    .
    $sqlCond = 'WHERE 1 '.$this->getAreaCondition($_POST['search_city']);
    .
    .
    $query = "SELECT `h`.*,".$countquery.",".$minquery." FROM `abserve_hotels` as `h`";

    $query1 = DB::select($query.$sqlCond);

    $perPage = 2;
    $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
    $pagedData = array_slice($query1, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
    $query1 =  new Paginator($pagedData, count($query1), $perPage);
    $query1->setPath('hotelresults');
    .
    .
    return view('hotel.list', $this->data,compact('query1'));
    }
```

Here,`setPath('hotelresults')` leads to my function while clicking my links in pagination

**View**

```
<?php 
if(!empty($query1)){
?>
@foreach($query1 as $aHotelRoom)

{{$aHotelRoom->hotel_id }}
{{$aHotelRoom->logo}}

@endforeach
<?php
echo $query1->render();
}
```

**Here,I found one thing that when we would like to pass the array from the controller we should use `$query1 = DB::select(...)` to write query and `return view('hotel.list',compact('query1'));` for passing that query as in array format to the view.**

It might useful for someone...

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know how to use...

`paginate(3)` will create collection where you'll have just 3 rows from your DB. Then `$users->render();` will create HTML pagination code. You must use `$users->render();` in hte view. You do not need to use `@foreach` or something like that to build pagination.

Example:

In controller:

```
$aHotelRooms = AHotelRoom::paginate(10);
return view('myview', compact('aHotelRooms'));
```

In the `myview.blade.php`:

```
$aHotelRooms->render();
```

Comment: But using `foreach` in my view only display all the contents..How should I display without `foreach`

Comment: I mean you shouldn't think of using `@foreach` for pagination.

Comment: I mean I'm having several things to be displayed in my view like `{{ $aHotelRoom->hotel_name }}` and `{{ $aHotelRoom->Address }}` etc. So how could I do this without using `foreach` in my view

Comment: You should use `@foreach` for this. You shouldn't use `@foreach` for pagination. Pagination is separation your data by pages and displaying links to other pages (1,2...4,5).

Comment: Then how should I paginate the contents in `foreach`..Is there any other ways to paginate those contents

Comment: Please re-read my post. The thing is you do not need to do anything to use pagination. Laravel will do everything for you automatically. All you need is to use `paginate()` and `render()` as I described in my answer.